# populate form fields in a loop with ajax

Tags: php, theme-development, ajax, jquery

The first row only works in my row.

```
<?PHP for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){ ?>
            <div id="lines" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><span id="row_number"><?PHP if ( $i < 10 ){ echo "0".$i;}else{echo $i;} ?></span></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080">
                    <select id="part_number" style="border:0px;">
                        <option value="None Selected"></option>
                        <?PHP
                            $partNumbers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM _cif_inventory_table;");
                                foreach ($partNumbers as $partNumber) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$partNumber->part_number.'">'.$partNumber->part_number.'</option>';
                                }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input size="5" maxlength="5" id="quantity" value="" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input size="75" id="description-<?PHP echo $i; ?>" value="" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input id="unitPrice-<?PHP echo $i; ?>" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input id="amount" value="" /></div>
            </div><!-- end .row -->
        <?PHP } ?>
```

I'm pretty sure it's the id's that aren't working as expected because they are all the same so I decided to add my loop counter to my id `<input size="75" id="description-<?PHP echo $i; ?>" value="" />` and `<input id="unitPrice-<?PHP echo $i; ?>" />` but I am confused on how to got this on the ajax side I tried to do it like

```
    $("#part_number").on('change', function() {
var part_number = $(this).val();
var row_number  = $('#row_number').html();

//alert("Row Number: " + row_number);

$.ajax({
    url: '<?PHP echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'description', part_number: part_number },
    success: function(data) {

        for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            $('#description-'+i).val( data );
        }

    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: '<?PHP echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'unit_price', part_number: part_number },
    success: function(data) {

        for ( var i = 1; i <= 20; $++) {
            $('#unitPrice-'+i).val( data );
        }

    }
});
});
```

but this populates every description field on the selection of the dropdown on row 1.

Comment: Need more context - bigger picture of what you are trying to do.  From what I can see, you should make a single ajax call with all of the form content (pass all your parts at once) instead of making a request for each row in the form.

Comment: I updated my ajax, but I'm not sure I am understanding you, this was my first attempt at ajax and I don't quite understand what I'm doing

Comment: Understood - there can be a lot to grok when diving into ajax.  The `data` you send with your ajax request is an object and could contain the description, unit_price and much more in a single ajax request.  Hopefully that makes sense.  http://www.joanmiquelviade.com/how-to-create-an-ajax-call-in-wordpress-step-by-step/